# Programmatically set the arrow tip of a popup

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, popup

I am missing the right terminology thus find it hard to Google / search for a solution -
nevertheless, I want to have the pointing arrow of a popup view pointing to different locations, take a look at the following image to see what I am talking about

[image: popup arrow]

questions

1. What is Apple's name / term of this element
2. How does one programmatically change it's position
3. Is this element supported by the SDK itself as an element and if state where

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `popoverArrowDirection` property of your [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html). Set it to one of the [UIPopoverArrowDirection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) values.

You can also specify the allowed direction in either of these functions for showing the popover:

```
presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
```

Answer (score 1):

try this it might help you.....

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(375, 230.0, 0.0, 0.0) inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```